# Why can't I use Unity 3D on a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series with FGLRX drivers?

Tags: 12.04, unity, ati, fglrx, 3d

With a brand new install of 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron M5030, Unity 3D appears to load everything but the icons in the top left, and I am unable to click on anything. Unity 2D seems to works fine however.

I have done nothing except install Synaptic Package manager and follow this [guide to install FGLRX Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers) under Settings → Additional Drivers, the driver shows as installed and functioning.

Also after running: `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`, I get this:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series
OpenGL version string:  3.3.11653 Compatibility Profile Context
Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes
Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

I am unsure as to what the problem is. I have tried the non-proprietary drivers, I could not get them to work either, but I would be willing to try again.

Comment: Bump- Anyone have any thoughts at all?

Comment: did you solved the problem yet ?